# What did common mode input voltage do for a fully differential opamp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, common-mode

I just want to know, what does the common mode input voltage in a fully differential op -amp do?

e.g. for a Op-amp,

$$V_1 = \dfrac{V_1 + V_2}{2}  + \dfrac{V_1 - V_2}{2}$$

$$V_2 = \dfrac{V_1 + V_2}{2}  + \dfrac{-(V_1 - V_2)}{2}$$

thus, \$\dfrac{V_1 + V_2}{2}\$ is the common part and \$\dfrac{V_1 - V_2}{2}\$ is the differential part of the signal.

There are three inputs, two are the differential voltage inputs. **One is the common mode voltage input. I do not know what this pin means?** Is it supply an offset?

for the Op Amp that i use is available under the link 
[THS4524](http://www.ti.com/product/ths4524?keyMatch=ths4524&tisearch=Search-EN-Everything)

[image]

Comment: Which opamp are you using?

Comment: Op amps typically DON'T have a common mode input.  Please attach part numbers and circuit diagrams, so we know what you're talking about

Comment: i haved posted the op amp that i used.

Comment: This part is not an operational amplifier.

Answer (score 2):

It's an **output** common-mode voltage, not input.  So, the output is differential around whatever voltage you apply to the common-mode pin (assuming you have enough headroom for it to still act like an opamp).

Comment: hi, thank you for your commemts. sorry, but i have posted the datasheet, it says it is Common mode voltage input。。。

Comment: sorry, but you don't understand the datasheet.  It is an input to the CHIP not an input to the amplifier.  Can you read a schematic?  Look at the functional block diagram of the chip you linked to.  You'll see that the common-mode input pin is used in a negative feedback loop to drive the common-mode (average) OUTPUT of the amplifier to the voltage you supply to the common-mode input pin.  This is pretty standard for a differential amplifier.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the online datasheet and scroll to the [Typical Applications page](http://www.ti.com/product/THS4524/datasheet/application_and_implementation#SBOS4585707), you'll see

> Figure 79 shows the modifications made to the circuit. Note the
>   resistor connecting the VOCM input of the THS4521 to the input
>   common-mode drive from the PCM4204 is shown removed and is optional;
>   no performance change was noted with it connected or removed.'

Also if you look at the [Electrical Specifications](http://www.ti.com/product/THS4524/datasheet/specifications#SBOS4587813), you will see that all the specs are measured with 'VOCM = Open'. So don't worry about it.

Like the other answer mentions it is an output voltage.

Answer (score 0):

It's an input with a twist. Look at this diagram - an amplifier (OPA2350) is feeding the "input": -

http://www.ti.com/ods/images/SBOS458G/typcir_ths_ads_test_bos458.gif

But, it can be left open circuit: -

[image]

Page 4 of the [data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ths4524.pdf) calls it an input so I'm quite happy to call it an input. Figure 53 also shows a graph of the input impedance of Vocm versus frequency.

BUT there is a voltage on it that can be used as a reference to other circuits. When left open circuit this pin naturally assumes the mid-point between the two supply rails. This can be a bias to another circuit but be prepared - it has to be buffered if feeding anything other than a light load. Figure 78 shows it as a potential divider formed from 2x 275kohm resistors connected to both rails.